# What does this entry in Windows Event log mean?

Tags: c#, event-log

Please help me about this log in Windows Event log. What does this mean?

障害が発生しているアプリケーション名: xxx.exe、バージョン: 1.0.0.0、タイム スタンプ: 0x4db446eb
障害が発生しているモジュール名: mscorwks.dll、バージョン: 2.0.50727.4927、タイム スタンプ: 0x4a275a68
例外コード: 0xc0000005
障害オフセット: 0x002063db
障害が発生しているプロセス ID: 0x%9
障害が発生しているアプリケーションの開始時刻: 0x%10
障害が発生しているアプリケーション パス: %11
障害が発生しているモジュール パス: %12
レポート ID: %13

(Sorry about Japanese)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) says:

```
Failing application name: xxx.exe, Version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4db446eb
Failing module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.4927, time stamp: 0x4a275a68
Exception Code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x002063db
Process ID that has failed: 0x% 9
Start time of an application that has failed: 0x% 10
Faulty application path:% 11
Module path that has failed:% 12
Report ID:% 13
```

`0xc0000005` is an access violation exception, something in the code is trying to access memory that doesn't belong to it (or doesn't exist).

Since `mscorwks.dll` is part of .Net, (I think) and will have been thoroughly tested, both by Microsoft and their "field testers" (i.e., users), it's more likely to be a problem in your `xxx.exe` application.

You might want to try running it under a debugger so you can more easily figure out exactly what the problem is. Debugging is usually more revealing than post-mortem analysis, *especially* for a generic problem like this that could have a thousand different causes.

Comment: And just to clarify, exception 0xc0000005 is the Windows HRESULT code for "Access Denied".

Comment: Actually, Joshua, "access denied" sounds more like the thing you get when trying to access a _file_ you're not supposed to. So, to clarify further, this is a _memory_ error :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now you know what it means if you want to troubleshoot this error get [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and reproduce the problem while taking a trace. Quickly stop Process Monitor when the error has occurred, then look for the Access Denied in the trace.

Could be a Permission issue or perhaps a file locking issue. As @Joshua and @paxdiablo mentioned 0xc0000005 is an "Access Denied" and the way we know that is by looking up the error code from the OS Header files using err.exe, you can find more info about the tool here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=be596899-7bb8-4208-b7fc-09e02a13696c&displaylang=en

ps mscorwks.dll is a core part of the .Net framework and is responsible for executing Common Language Runtime (CLR).

Comment: sorry, it has nothing to do with permissions or file locking, it's a _memory_ access issue as that tool plainly states: `_STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION: The instruction at ONEPLACE referenced memory at ANOTHERPLACE. The memory could not be SOMETHINGED.`. Kudos for the tool however, it's a lot easier than searching all those files for an error :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a program provided by the spanish Social Insurance using a relatively old version of the Crystal Reports Libraries. And here is how I fixed it:

- Right-click "My PC" --> Properties
- Advanced System Configuration
- Performance
- Data Execution Prevention

I added the program that was crashing (in my case it was a Buffer Overflow in the Stack Trace) to the list of exceptions

Problem solved! Runs like a charm now.